# Unknown option "squirrelFirstrun" MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

how to solved this issue? when im trying to install mongo compass
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lxl7.png)

i dont know how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install compass and service in different ways.

- install mongo service first and uncheck the install mongo compass option.
- then download and install mongodb compass at https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass and install it.
  choose the stable version of mongo compass

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

msi package works for me :)

> ( exe package didn't work for me :( )